# Is there a 180 days rule on UK ICT Short Term (1 year) Visa?

Tags: uk-visa

Can anyone help me out with this scenario:

- I left UK on 25th Nov 2016
- I might be landing in UK on 21st May 2017 (i.e. 178 days)
- This travel is for about 3 months, ending 19th August 2017 (i.e. 90 days)
- Visa is valid until 22nd August 2017

Is is valid to travel? and what else needs to be produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK does not have such a rule. However, the country has electronic records of all entries and exits and, if it appears that you’re trying to live there through frequent visits, or perform activities not permitted under your visa, you may be subjected to increased scrutiny at the border.

Depending on circumstances, you can be allowed to enter and stay as planned, landed for only a specific amount of time and/or with conditions, or you can be refused entry (and your visa cancelled). Additionally, it could affect future visa applications.

It is always advisable to bring with you the same documentation used in applying for the visa (as cumbersome as that may be).